# How to set up properly package_data in setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py

I am facing an error like **No such file or directory...**. Could anyone help me with this out? I'd really appreciate it! This is the directory: [image]

And this is the setup.py code:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='raw-microsoft-wwi',
    version='1.0.0',
    package_dir={"":"src"},
    packages=[
        "raw_microsoft_wwi",
        "raw_microsoft_wwi.configuration",
        "raw_microsoft_wwi.reader",
        "raw_microsoft_wwi.writer",
        "raw_microsoft_wwi.transformer"
    ],
    package_data = {"src/raw_microsoft_wwi/queries": ["*.sql"]},
    include_package_data = True,
    install_requires=[
        "delta-spark==1.2.0",
        "pyspark==3.2.1",
        "python-environ==0.4.54"
    ],
    zip_safe=False
)
```

Comment: the best answer I could think of is to go through this documentation. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) Hope this will answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setuptools expects `package_data` to be a dictionary mapping from Python package names to a list of file name patterns.

This means that the keys in the dictionary should be similar to the values you listed in the `packages` configuration (instead of paths).

I think you can try the following:

1. Add the missing `raw_microsoft_wwi.queries`, `raw_microsoft_wwi.queries.incremental_table_queries`, `raw_microsoft_wwi.queries.regular_tables_queries` (etc) to the `packages` list (effectivelly all these folders are considered packages by Python, even if they don't have a `__init__.py` file).
2. Replace `package_data`, with something similar to:

```py
package_data = {"raw_microsoft_wwi.queries": ["**/*.sql"]}
```

More information is available in https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html.